# Show asp.net Wizard Control SideBar on top instead of on side

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard

I currently create a wizard and its steps programmatically and I am trying to show the default side bar with its links to each step on the top instead of the side. Is this possible?

```
Wizard wiz = new Wizard();
//Do stuff with wizard steps
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with CSS

**ASP.NET declarative code**

```
    <asp:Wizard ID="ApplicationWizard" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="True">
        <%-- LAYOUT --%>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="headerPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div id="stepIndicator">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="sideBarPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="WizardStepPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <%-- HEADER --%>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h1 class="text-center">My Form</h1>
            <%-- TODO: Add your header elements here --%>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <%-- SIDEBAR --%>
        <SideBarTemplate>
            <ul id="header">
                <asp:ListView ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="sideBarButton" runat="server" /></li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemTemplate>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="sideBarButton" runat="server" CssClass="active-step" /></li>
                    </SelectedItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </ul>
        </SideBarTemplate>

        <%-- Wizard Steps --%>
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:TemplatedWizardStep ID="AppStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <%-- TODO: Add your wizard step elements here --%>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TemplatedWizardStep>

            <asp:TemplatedWizardStep ID="AppStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2">
                <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TemplatedWizardStep>

            <asp:TemplatedWizardStep ID="AppStep3" runat="server" Title="Step 3">
                <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TemplatedWizardStep>

            <asp:TemplatedWizardStep ID="AppStep4" runat="server" Title="Step 4">
                <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TemplatedWizardStep>

            <asp:TemplatedWizardStep ID="AppStep5" runat="server" Title="Step 5">
                <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TemplatedWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

**CSS Stylesheet**

```
#stepIndicator {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#stepIndicator li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#stepIndicator li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

**But how???:**

1. On the SideBar template, create a list element
2. Inside the nested **lis**, insert the link button you want
3. The output will be the default format (sidebar on the side)
4. Add `text-align: center` for `#stepIndicator` to center the sidebar
5. Add `display: inline-block` for `#stepIndicator li` to align the the elements of `#stepIndicator` inline.